# How to detect when candles touch inside box

Tags: pine-script

I need to detect when candle 3 or 4 come inside box (pic below). A box forms simply when a green candle closes above high of previous red candle - or vise versa.

[image]

So after candle 4 closes, it will check if candle 3 or 4 has touched the box, if it has, the box will not be printed, but if there are no touches, then the box will print.

*** Edit: This is the code I have now. Trying to first do red box. It is probably all over the place as the code is chop and changed. Also how would I add the candle count as an input setting? Thanks

```
indicator('candle pattern', overlay=true, max_lines_count=500)

len = input.int(2, "Box Length")

greenCandle = (close > open)
redCandle = (close < open)

f_is_within(val, top) => (val <= top)

if close < low[1] and greenCandle[1]
    redBox=box.new(left=bar_index[1], top=math.max(high[1], high[1]),
         right=bar_index + len, bottom=math.min(low[1], low[1]),
         bgcolor=color.new(color.red, 50), border_color=color.new(color.red, 80), border_width=1),
         box_top = box.get_top(redBox),
         f_is_within(low, box_top)


// if close > high[1] and redCandle[1]
//     greenBox=box.new(left=bar_index[1], top=math.max(low[1], low[1]),
//          right=bar_index + len, bottom=math.min(high[1], high[1]),
//          bgcolor=color.new(color.green, 50), border_color=color.new(color.green, 80), border_width=1),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `box.get_x` functions to get the cordinates of the box. Then simply check if the price is within this box.

```
f_is_within(val, top, bot) => (val <= top) and (val >= bot)
box_top = box.get_top(box_id)
box_bot = box.get_bottom(box_id)

is_price_within_box = f_is_within(high, box_top, box_bot) or f_is_within(low, box_top, box_bot)
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your answer. So for the (box_id), I tried using 'greenBox', after adding it to my code like:  `greenBox=box.new` etc. But it said undeclared identifier. As said before, I know very little of coding hah. This code was built from a couple of other lines of code I found

Comment: Please edit yuor question and add your new code there.

Comment: I've edited the main post with my code now.